# Kotlin raw string throws blank error

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, rawstring

I'm creating a gradle plugin using kotlin and I am inserting some ascii art. Rather than trying to escape a load of backslashes, I decided to use raw strings but now I'm encountering bizarre nameless errors whenever my line contains 2 vertical bars.

Here's some sample code:

```
println("""
        ] |___1
        ] ||__2
        ] |||_3 
        ] ||||4
        """.trimMargin("]"))
```

This results in the following errors in my message log:

```
Error:__2
Error:|_3
Error:||4
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening? I've overwritten the margin character so I don't understand why the vertical bar is still affecting the raw string. It's odd that it only happens from the second bar onward.

It's a purely cosmetic part of the project so it's not a huge deal if I have to remove it.

Any insight is appreciated!

**Edit:**

I've since restarted my computer and IDE and now the sample string I supplied doesn't cause those errors. However my ascii string still does so I'll supply a snippet of the art that gives errors.

I'm also using kotlin 1.1.0 and have tried downgrading to 1.0.6 and still see the errors.

New sample code:

```
println("""
        ]                      \                    ^    /^
        ]                       \                  / \  // \
        ]                        \   |\___/|      /   \//  .\
        ]                         \  /O  O  \__  /    //  | \ \           *----*
        ]                           /     /  \/_/    //   |  \  \          \   |
        ]                           @___@`    \/_   //    |   \   \         \/\ \
        ]                          0/0/|       \/_ //     |    \    \         \  \
        ]                      0/0/0/0/|        \///      |     \     \       |  |
        ]                   0/0/0/0/0/_|_ /   (  //       |      \     _\     |  /
        ]                0/0/0/0/0/0/`/,_ _ _/  ) ; -.    |    _ _\.-~       /   /
        """.trimMargin("]"))
```

Gives these errors:

```
Error:/   \//  .\
Error:
Error:\    \         \  \
Error:\     \       |  |
Error:\     _\     |  /
```

Comment: interesting, i just tried your println statement here on the JVM and it works 
http://try.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: I can't replicate the issue either. It works exactly as expected on try.kotlinlang.org and on my local machine.

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using? Do you have any conflicting versions on the classpath?

Comment: Cheers for the response guys, I'll update the question now with some new information

Comment: I tried the statement in your new edited information.  It works.  I am using kotlin 1.3.41 and JDK 11